# Record incoming MIDI data and playing it back in real time c++

Tags: c++, streaming, midi

I suppose it could be any type of input data, but I’m looking to create a real-time midi sequencer. I am just getting started in c++ and I know it’s ambitious but I’m starting to get the hang of the code now and am wondering if my approach is correct.  I have started to to try Juce but it seems somewhat proprietary to Juce custom header files. So I’m simply going to ask if anyone can help me understand the process of starting a stream that will receive a start command, a stop command, and input data in a timeline.

Do I create a vector that gets divided into quarter notes?  How do I then ‘Start’ the vector to begin recording, even if it’s recording no input?

Hope I’m not being too general in my request.

Thanks in advance all.

Comment: Read the [Standard MIDI Files specification](https://www.midi.org/specifications-old/item/the-midi-1-0-specification) to find out which data you need to store.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes I will investigate the code that needs to be received but I guess my question isn’t clear enough. I’m inquiring about how to start recording a data stream that listens for data in a timeline. Much like a tape recorder. Then can play it back in the same timeline as it was inputted.   I’m thinking my question might require too large an answer.   Thanks for your reply.